# Button inside calendar event - Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the calendar component of Vuetify. I have a requirement to show and hide some information inside a calendar event on the click of button which resides inside the same event. I am able to show or hide the div but it happens for all the calendar event not just the next to the clicked button. Can someone help me out?

[image: Calendar-Vuetify]

Adding the code below -

```
 <v-calendar
              ref="calendar"
              v-model="focus"
              color="primary"
              :events="events"
              :event-color="getEventColor"
              :type="type"
              first-interval="6"
              interval-height="72"
              @click:more="viewDay"
              @click:date="viewDay"
              @change="updateRange"
            >
              <template v-slot:event="{ event }">
                <div>
                  <div
                    class="ml-8 mr-12 mt-5 pb-2"
                    style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0063a7; display: flow-root"
                  >
                    <div style="float: left">
                      <div class="mr-4" style="float: left">
                        <v-btn
                          id="btn-open"
                          text
                          icon
                          color="#0063A7"
                          v-on:click="ShowDetails()"
                          ><v-icon large>mdi-menu-down</v-icon></v-btn
                        >
                        <v-btn
                          id="btn-close"
                          text
                          icon
                          color="#0063A7"
                          style="display: none"
                          ><v-icon large>mdi-menu-up</v-icon></v-btn
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p class="event-header-time">
                          {{ event.time }}
                        </p>
                        <p class="event-header-name" style="font-weight: bold">
                          {{ event.name }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right">
                      <v-btn class="event-header-btn" text
                        >Begin Inventory<v-icon class="pl-5"
                          >mdi-arrow-right</v-icon
                        ></v-btn
                      >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                    <div v-show="selectedOpen" id="div-event-data">
                      <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
              </template>
            </v-calendar>

    export default {
      name: "calender",
      data: () => ({
        focus: "",
        type: "day",
        typeToLabel: {
          month: "Month",
          week: "Week",
          day: "Day",
          "4day": "4 Days",
        },
        selectedEvent: {},
        selectedElement: null,
        selectedOpen: false,
        events: [
          {
            time: "10:00 - 11:30",
            name: "Pharmacy B | SUNS008",
            start: "2021-05-13 10:00:00",
            end: "2021-05-13 11:30:00",
            color: "cyan",
          },
          {
            name: "test",
            start: "2021-05-14 07:00:00",
            end: "2021-05-14 07:25:00",
            color: "green",
          },
          {
            name: "test",
            start: "2021-05-16 08:00:00",
            end: "2021-05-16 08:15:00",
            color: "red",
          },
          {
            time: "8:00 AM - 9:00 AM",
            name: "Pharmacy B | SUNS008",
            start: "2021-05-23 08:00:00",
            end: "2021-05-23 11:00:00",
            color: "#E8F4FE",
            selectedOpen: false,
          },
          {
            name: "test",
            start: "2021-05-23 13:00:00",
            end: "2021-05-23 15:00:00",
            color: "#E8F4FE",
          },
          {
            name: "test",
            start: "2021-05-23 18:00:00",
            end: "2021-05-23 19:15:00",
            color: "#E8F4FE",
          },
        ],
        colors: [
          "blue",
          "indigo",
          "deep-purple",
          "cyan",
          "green",
          "orange",
          "grey darken-1",
        ],
        names: [
          "<h1>Meeting</h1>",
          "Holiday",
          "PTO",
          "Travel",
          "Event",
          "Birthday",
          "Conference",
          "Party",
        ],
      }),
      mounted() {
        this.$refs.calendar.checkChange();
      },
      methods: {
        viewDay({ date }) {
          this.focus = date;
          this.type = "day";
        },
        getEventColor(event) {
          return event.color;
        },
        setToday() {
          this.focus = "";
        },
        prev() {
          this.$refs.calendar.prev();
        },
        next() {
          this.$refs.calendar.next();
        },
        ShowDetails(event) {
      const open = () => {
        this.selectedEvent = event;
        this.selectedElement = event.target;
        this.selectedOpen = true;
      };
      if (this.selectedOpen) {
        this.selectedOpen = false;
      } else {
        open();
      }
      //nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
    },
        updateRange() {},
        rnd(a, b) {
          return Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random()) + a;
        },
      },
    };
```

Comment: please, share some code otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: @niccord - I have added the HTML and script. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new property to your events, called `expanded`. Then instead of `@click="showDetails()"` use `@click="event.expanded = !event.expanded"`.

Then, put your conditionally rendered DIV inside the event template and use `<div v-show="event.expanded">....</div>`